# What's wrong with my animation function?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

It animates but it put's the piece of the sprite sheet where it is on the sprite sheet and not where the x and y tell it to. It's very short, so please take a look? Thank you in advance.

```
package cyanprime{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class Player{
        [Embed(source="brownplane.png")]
        public var image:Class;
        public var bitmapdata:BitmapData = getBitmap(new image());
        public var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapdata);
        public var speed:int = 5;
        public var x:int = 50;
        public var y:int = 50;
        public var frame:int = 0;

        public function getBitmap(img:DisplayObject):BitmapData{
            var drawRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle((img.width/3) * frame, 0, img.width/3, img.height);
            var bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(img.width, img.height);
            bitmap.draw(img,null,null,null,drawRect);
            return bitmap;
        }

        public function animate():void{
            bitmap.bitmapData = getBitmap(new image());
            frame++;

            if(frame > 2)
                frame = 0;

            bitmap.x = x;
            bitmap.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you change the x and y? looks untouched to me. Too less info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add a matrix transform to draw() to translate the position of the rectangle being drawn. Something like this:

```
var trans:Matrix = new Matrix();
trans.tx = drawRect.x;
bitmap.draw(img,trans,null,null,drawRect);
```

If that doesn't work, try `-drawRect.x`, I can't exactly remember how that transform is applied.